# Connecting mock and client in django's tests

Tags: django, testing, mocking

I've written two classes: System and Order which represent something like "online ticket distribution store".

Making order is easy:

```
order = Order('title', set(['1', '2', '5']))
System.fill(order)
```

but I would like to test my views.fill_order function, and check if it's filling the order from POST parameters correctly. To do this I can use mock and client like this:

```
from core.order import Order
from core.system import System
from django.test.client import Client
from mock import Mock, sentinel

self.logged_client = Client()
# skipping logging process

Order = Mock(sentinel.return_value)
System = Mock()
System.fill = Mock()

# sending hypotetic POST
self.logged_client.post('/my_view_url/', {'title': self.PHANTOM, 'seat_numbers': '1I', 'seat_numbers': '3IV'})

System.fill.assert_called_with(Order.return_value)
Order.assert_called_with(self.PHANTOM, set(['1I', '2II', '3IV']))
```

But ... it's not working (asserts fails). How to fix it?

I know it's because inside my views.fill_order function I do:

```
from core.system import System
from core.order import Order
```

once again, but how to force this classes to be mocked during test persistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to mocking successfully is to remember that you need to replace the objects in the module where they're actually used, not where your tests are defined. So, in your case, you want to import the view module and replace the classes there:

```
from core.whatever import views
views.System = my_mock_system
views.Order = my_mock_order
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not working when mocking and using the client, because it seems to be launching a different instance of project, without the mocked Classes.
I had no success on doing that, the only way seems to be to instance the class itself...